# Где лучше хранить статьи для блогов и информационных сайтов?

Tags: оптимизация, seo, оптимизация-сайтов

Где лучше хранить статьи для сайтов типа "блог" и "информационный портал" - в файлах или базах данных? На данный момент у меня нет аругменов ни за, ни против конкретного метода.

`Wordpress` и другие CMS я использовать не собираюсь, так что пожалуйста, не упоминайте про них в ответе.

Comment: Не хотите cms делайте как в старые добрые времена на чистом html ;)

Answer (score 2):

Считаю что лучше хранить в бд, на то она и база данных, удобно, универсально, практично. Опять же в бд существуют транзакции, внутренние функции, ограничители прав доступа и так далее.